# echo out image in mysql while loop not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a message type system set up and i am using a mysql while loop to echo out the contents from my table and am also trying to echo out the users profile image so that it appears next to each result being echoed. since this is a 2 way message system their is the photo of 'to_user_id'/recipient and 'from_user_id'/sender. this are coded as $photo and $photo2

its all working fine, the images are coming out as they should for each result being echoed by the while loop, however and for some reason, the first result is not echoing out the image, just the div container

does anyone know why this is. heres my code, thanks.

```
<div class="message_field">
<div class="inner_frame">   

<?
$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_messages
                        WHERE msg_id like '%".$query."%'");
                        $inbox_set = get_inbox();
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
if ($data_fetch['from_user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){

{


$photo = "data/photos/{$data_fetch['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg";
if (!file_exists($photo)) {
    $photo = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";


} 


$photo2 = "data/photos/{$data_fetch['to_user_id']}/_default.jpg";
if (!file_exists($photo2)) {
    $photo2 = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";


} 



?>


<div class="message_bubble2">
<div class="msg_bubble_img"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['id']}\"><img src="<?php echo $photo ?>" width="40" heigh="40" border="0"></a></div><?php echo "".$data_fetch['content']."";?><div class="message_bubble_tail2"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail2_shadow"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail2_shadow_bottom"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail2_outline"></div>
<div class="message_bubble_footer2">
<?php
$inbox_set = get_inbox();
while ($inbox = mysql_fetch_array($inbox_set)) { ?>
<?php echo "".$review_from."";  ?>&nbsp;<?
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime ($reviews['date_added']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));
$labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
$i = 0;
foreach($mdhms as $t){
  if($t > 0) break;
  $i+=1;
}
echo "sent by you ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago"; } ?>
</div></div>


<? 
}
}else{


if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
if ($data_fetch['from_user_id'] !== $_SESSION['user_id']){

{

?>  


<div class="message_bubble"><div class="msg_bubble_img2"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['id']}\"><img src="<?php echo $photo2 ?>" width="40" heigh="40" border="0"></a></div><?php echo "".$data_fetch['content']."";?><div class="message_bubble_tail"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail_shadow"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail_shadow_bottom"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail_outline"></div>
<div class="message_bubble_footer">
<?php
$inbox_set = get_inbox();
while ($inbox = mysql_fetch_array($inbox_set)) { ?>
<?php echo "".$review_from."";  ?>&nbsp;<?
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime ($reviews['date_added']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));
$labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
$i = 0;
foreach($mdhms as $t){
  if($t > 0) break;
  $i+=1;
}
echo "sent from ".$inbox['from_user_id']." ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago"; } ?>
</div></div>


<? } } } } } ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: run you query in mysql directly and check first row is coming as output or not

Comment: Looks like this might be an ORDER issue. You seem to set up the details of the image where $data_fetch['from_user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'] then output them where $data_fetch['from_user_id'] != $_SESSION['user_id'] . However nothing in the SELECT to force the first situation to happen before the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the order of the SELECT statement:-

```
<?

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) 
{ 
    $query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT *, IF(from_user_id= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."', 0, 1) AS ForceOrder
                            FROM ptb_messages
                            WHERE msg_id like '%".$query."%'
                            ORDER BY ForceOrder, ");
                            $inbox_set = get_inbox();
    while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
    {
        if ($data_fetch['from_user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'])
        {
            {
                $photo = "data/photos/{$data_fetch['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg";
                if (!file_exists($photo)) 
                {
                    $photo = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
                } 
                $photo2 = "data/photos/{$data_fetch['to_user_id']}/_default.jpg";
                if (!file_exists($photo2)) 
                {
                    $photo2 = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
                } 
                ?>
                <div class="message_bubble2">
                <div class="msg_bubble_img"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['id']}\"><img src="<?php echo $photo ?>" width="40" heigh="40" border="0"></a></div><?php echo "".$data_fetch['content']."";?><div class="message_bubble_tail2"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail2_shadow"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail2_shadow_bottom"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail2_outline"></div>
                <div class="message_bubble_footer2">
                <?php
                $inbox_set = get_inbox();
                while ($inbox = mysql_fetch_array($inbox_set)) 
                { ?>
                    <?php echo "".$review_from."";  ?>&nbsp;<?
                    $datetime1 = new DateTime();
                    $datetime2 = new DateTime ($reviews['date_added']);
                    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                    $mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));
                    $labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($mdhms as $t)
                    {
                      if($t > 0) break;
                      $i+=1;
                    }
                    echo "sent by you ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago"; 
                } ?>
                </div></div>


                <? 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) 
            { 
                if ($data_fetch['from_user_id'] !== $_SESSION['user_id'])
                {
                    {
                        ?>  
                        <div class="message_bubble"><div class="msg_bubble_img2"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['id']}\"><img src="<?php echo $photo2 ?>" width="40" heigh="40" border="0"></a></div><?php echo "".$data_fetch['content']."";?><div class="message_bubble_tail"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail_shadow"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail_shadow_bottom"></div><div class="message_bubble_tail_outline"></div>
                        <div class="message_bubble_footer">
                        <?php
                        $inbox_set = get_inbox();
                        while ($inbox = mysql_fetch_array($inbox_set)) 
                        { ?>
                            <?php echo "".$review_from."";  ?>&nbsp;<?
                            $datetime1 = new DateTime();
                            $datetime2 = new DateTime ($reviews['date_added']);
                            $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                            $mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));
                            $labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
                            $i = 0;
                            foreach($mdhms as $t)
                            {
                                if($t > 0) break;
                                $i+=1;
                            }
                            echo "sent from ".$inbox['from_user_id']." ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago"; 
                        } ?>
                        </div></div>


                        <? 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
?>
```